# QGIS-Server LeafLet Layer Order

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, qgis

I have a leaflet project rendering `L.TileLayers.WMS` and `L.GeoJSON` layers. The WMS and GeoJSON layers are served by QGIS-Server. I am trying to reorder the layers using `pane` for the GeoJSON and `zIndex` for the WMS layers and `bringToFront()` and `bringToBack()` methods. None of them is doing the job.

It seems that WMS layers are loaded following the order in QGIS project .qgs. Could anyone point me what I am missing in the code bellow:

```
let qgisserverBaseURL = 'http://10.0.0.113/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?'

let cbers4Options = {
    map: '/home/qgis/project/inde.qgs',
    layers: 'cbers4',
    zIndex: 500,
    tiled: true,
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
    version: '1.3.0'
} 
 let cbers4 = new L.TileLayer.WMS(qgisserverBaseURL, cbers4Options)

map.createPane('pane400');
map.getPane('pane400').style.zIndex = 400;
map.getPane('pane400').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

let biomas = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    style: biomas_style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pane: 'pane400'

});

let overLayers = {
  
    'cbers4': cbers4,
    'biomas': biomas,

};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overLayers, {
    collapsed: false,
}).addTo(map);
```

According to this configuration, the cbers4 layer should appear on top of the biomas layer, but it is not going through. If I use the `cbers4.bringToFront()` and `biomas.bringToBack()` methods, the layer order does not change either. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You talk about «the `cbers4` layer», but I see no mention of a `cbers4` variable in your  code. You'll need to supply the (relevant parts of the) code where you're instantiating the rest of the layers for everyone else to understand what's going on.

Comment: I suspect this will boil down to a lack of understanding of how [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) work. The `z-index` of a Leaflet layer is relative to its containing pane, and `z-index` of panes are relative to the map.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I added some more information. Based on zIndex and pane, cbers4 layer should be on top of biomas, but it does not.

Comment: Yup, stacking context misunderstanding, as I suspected. Do read the linked article, keep in mind that a Leaflet map pane both defines a stacking context and has a `z-index` on its containing stacking context.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I just  changed the option for L.TileLayer.WMS from zIndex to pane and that is it.